# Añadir restricción SQL a tabla ya creada

Tags: postgresql, constraints

Necesito añadir una restricción a una tabla de mi bbdd que afecta a dos columnas, en la tabla clientes, tengo la columna 'city' que tiene como DEFAULT 'España' y la columna 'phone'que admite valores nulos.
Y ahora necesito crear restricción que diga si añado cliente nuevo extranjero, que no sea de España, la columna 'phone' NO puede tener valor NULL.
Mi intento es:

```
CREATE CONSTRAIN Constraint1 CHECK (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                        FROM erp.tb_site 
                        WHERE site_phone = NULL AND 
                        cite_country <> 'España'))
```

Algo estoy haciendo mal evidentemente.
Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: `CONSTRAINT`...

Comment: Perdon, me he equivocado al escribir el codigo aquí, sí que he puesto CONSTRAINT en pgAdmin4 pero me salen errores igual.

Comment: ¿Y que errores tienes? agrega esto a tu pregunta.

Comment: Finalmente lo pude resolver dandole una vuelta, quité el NOT EXISTS i en la condicion WHERE hice como site_phone NOT NULL. Gracias de todas formas

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE NombreTabla ADD CONSTRAINT...
```

Comment: el codigo que agregas no funciona, tal vez necesite un `;`